# Reference about Moduli Spaces of Riemann surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry, moduli-space

I'm looking for some (introductory, and in any case not too technical) reference (book, lecture notes, papers) regarding

- moduli spaces $\mathcal{M}_g$ and $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$ of (punctured) Riemann surfaces, then Teichmuller spaces, its dimension, and the application of Riemann-Roch to $\mathcal{M}_g$
- generalization to unoriented and open setup, in particular Weichold theorem and the covering space construction
- relation of the above with moduli spaces of stable maps, particularly the work of Kontsevich using decorated graphs to count maps

Comment: The first place I'd look is Farb & Margalit, Primer on Mapping Class Groups.

Comment: You might find the answer to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513970) interesting.