# Recap of Riemann's original proof of the dimension of Moduli space $M_g$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to understand some single steps in [this
recap](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347378)  of Bernhard Riemann's original proof by Alexandre Eremenko
that the moduli space $M_g$
of compact Riemann surfaces with genus $g \ge 2$ has dimension
$3g-3$ (or in original context the $3g-3$ 'degrees of freedom' are
what Riemann called 'moduli')

> Riemann combines what is called Riemann-Roch and Riemann-Hurwitz nowadays.
> He considers the dimension of the space of holomorphic maps of degree $d$
> from the Riemann surface of genus $g$ to the sphere. He computes this dimension
> in two ways. By Riemann-Roch this dimension is
> $2d-g+1$, for a fixed Riemann surface. (Indeed, Riemann-Roch says that
> the dimension of the space of such functions with $d$ poles fixed
> is $d-g+1$ (when $d\geq 2g-1$ which we may assume), but these poles can
> be moved, so one has to add $d$ parameters).

> On the other hand, such a function has $2(d+g-1)$ critical points by
> Riemann-Hurwitz. Generically, the critical values are distinct, and can
> be arbitrarily assigned, and this gives the dimension of the set of
> all such maps on all Riemann surfaces
> of genus $g$.

> So the space of all Riemann surfaces of genus $g$ must be of dimension
> $$2(d+g-1)-(2d-g+1)=3g-3.$$

There are essentially two things I struggle with.

**Point 1:** Why the dimension of the space of holomorphic maps
of degree $d$ from the Riemann surface $S$ of genus $g$ to the sphere
equals $2d-g+1$?

As far as can follow we are going to apply RR. Let $h$ any
holomorphic map $S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$ which we regard as
meromorphic function $h$ which behaves compatible with degree $d$ in
it's poles and zeros, set $(h) :=D$ and apply RR to it.
RR tells $l(D)= d -g+1$ where $l(D)$ is the $C$-dimension of
meromorphic functions $f$ on $S$
such that all the coefficients of the divisors $(f) + D$ are non-negative.

Eremenko argues then that the additional $d$ dimensions
we obtain because 'the poles of can be moved, so one has to
add $d$ parameters.'

I not understand why moving of the $d$ poles gives additionally exaxt
$d$ parameters.

**Point 2:** Why the difference

$$ 2(d+g-1)-(2d-g+1) $$

between the number of critical points of these moromorphic functions
(that's Riemann-Hurwitz-Thm) and the counted dimension of
the space of holomorphic maps of degree $d$ from point 1 gives exactly
the dimension of the moduli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To specify a degree $d$ map $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$, one first chooses an effective divisor $D$ of degree $d$ to specify the poles of $f$. Since $D$ has support consisting of $d$ points, this amounts to $d$ choices. So this by this "the poles can be moved" comment, he means that choosing a different divisor $D'$ will result in a different map with poles given by the support of $D'$ instead. Then one computes $\ell(D)$ as you have described above to get the dimension of the space of degree $d$ maps $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ with $\renewcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}} \div_\infty(f) = D$.
2. We want to compute the dimension of $\mathcal{M}_g$, the moduli space of curves of genus $g$, but what we've really done is computed the dimension of the moduli space of pairs $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a curve of genus $g$ and $f$ is a degree $d$ map $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$. This related moduli space is called a *Hurwitz space*, denoted $\DeclareMathOperator{\Hur}{Hur} \Hur_{d,g}$. In order to remove this choice of a map $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1$, we subtract off the dimension of the space of degree $d$ maps $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ which was computed above.

   You can interpret this using the projection
   \begin{align*}
   \pi: \Hur_{d,g} &\to \mathcal{M}_g\\
   (X,f) &\mapsto X \, .
   \end{align*}
   We've computed the dimension of $\Hur_{d,g}$ and, for a given $X$, the dimension of the fiber $\pi^{-1}(X)$. Assuming $\pi$ is sufficiently "nice", we should have
   \begin{align*}
   \dim(\mathcal{M}_g) = \dim(\Hur_{d,g}) - \dim(\pi^{-1}(X)) = 2d + 2g - 2 - (2d - g + 1) = 3g-3 \, ,
   \end{align*}
   as desired.

This is covered in greater detail in chapter 2, section 3 (p. 255) of *Principles Of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris. Jarod Alper also recently covered this in a lecture for a course he's teaching, which you can watch [here](https://youtu.be/nfVyMG6fil8?t=936). (See [here](https://youtu.be/nfVyMG6fil8?t=1432) for the dimension calculation you've asked about.)

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513970/what-is-the-best-way-to-see-that-the-dimension-of-the-moduli-space-of-curves-of).

Comment: The point $2$ meanwhile presumably I understand. In summary 
there exist an dense open
subset $U \subset \DeclareMathOperator{\Hur}{Hur} \Hur_{d,g}$ over
which the restriction of the projection of $\pi$ to $\pi \vert _U$
behaves 'like a fibre bundle' from dimensional conting point of view,
thus the the formula $\dim(\mathcal{M}_g) = 
\dim(\Hur_{d,g}) - \dim(\pi^{-1}(X))$, right?

Comment: About the point $1$ I still not sure if I understand
it completely. I would to explain the proble i see.
 We fix a Riemann surface
$X$ and want to deduce that the dimension of the holom maps of degree $d$
$X \to P^1$ equals exactly $\ell(D)+ d$. As you said every such map 
has an associated divisor $D$ of deg $d$ which is supported in $d$
points (counted with multiplimities). And RR says $\ell(D)=d-g +1$.
Then we vary these $d$ points slowly say from $D:= \{p_1,...,p_d\}$ to
$D':=\{p'_1,...,p'_d\}$.

Comment: Since all these points live on $X$, which is a
$1$-dim manifold, so the variation of every point $p \in X$ separately
contributes exactly one 'degree of freedom' =$\mathbb{C}$-dimension, as far correct? But now I see a problem:

Comment: essentially, up to now counted the dimensions like in case of 
a product vector spaces $V and W$: $\operatorname{dim}(V \times W)= 
\operatorname{dim}(V) + \operatorname{dim}(W)$ where the 
role of $L$ plays for a fixed divisor $D$ the space $L(D)$ and 
of $W$ the 'naked' variation of $d$ points (which corresponds to a 
$d$-dimensional space. But here I see a problem that it could 
be not so easy just to add these dimensions:  In case of $V \times W$ that works since for $w \neq w' \in W$ the spaces 
$V \times \{w\} $ and $V \times \{w'\} $ are **disjoint.**

Comment: In our case it could happen
that for different divisors $D \neq D'$ the intersection $L(D) \cap L(D')$
could have a positive dimension: $\operatorname{dim}(L(D) \cap L(D')) > 0$(see below why),
especially these might be not disjoint, so I'm not
sure why we can here just add the dimensions of $L(D)$ (for arbitrary $D$)
together with the 'space of variation of $d$ points' like in case
of product space $V \times W$.

Comment: (on why) recall that for a fixed divisor $D$ the 
space of holom maps of degree $d$ with resp $D$ is defined as
$L(D):=\left\{f: X\rightarrow {\mathbb  {P}}^{1}
{\mbox{ holomomorphic}}\,|\,\left(f\right) -D \geq 0 \right\}$
and therefore by this definition for different $D \neq D'$ it could 
happen that $\operatorname{dim}(L(D) \cap L(D')) > 0$.

Comment: Do you see how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your objection, but I think the answer is that the sets you're concerned about are of strictly smaller dimension, so they don't affect the dimension. Note that not every function in $L(D)$ has pole divisor $D$. Indeed, there are many that don't, the constant functions, for instance. However the elements $L(D)$ with pole divisor $\neq D$ are in a Zariski-closed subset of strictly smaller dimension. So really we don't want to compute the dimension of $L(D)$, but of the dense open subset $U_D$ of $L(D)$ consisting of functions $f$ with pole divisor $D$.

Comment: These $U_D$ are disjoint for different choices of $D$ by definition. And indeed, any function in $L(D) \cap L(D’)$ can’t have pole divisor $D$ or $D’$: it must have some pole divisor $D’’$ made up of some combination of the supports of $D$ and $D’$. Let me know if that resolves your concern.

Comment: My objection was that in **point 1** the calulation of
 the dimension of the holom maps of degree $d$ for **fixed**
Riemann surface $X$ based on
addition of the dimensions of the space $L(D)$ ($D$ could be choosen arbitrary
in spirit of RR) and the dimension 
of $d$-dimensional "space" $Div(X, d)$ of degree $d$ divisors as if
these both $C$-vectorspaces were regarded (at least locally) as
parts of product space $L(D) \times D(X,d)$ but in order
to assure that the dimension of the space of the holom maps 
$X \to P^1$ of degree $d$ coincides

Comment: with 
$dim(L(D))+dim(Div(X, d))= d-g+1+g$ we have to check that
(at least locally) the space of the holom maps of degree $d$ 
looks like the product $L(D) \times D(X,d)$.
But in contast to 'classical' product space the problem
here was that for two $D \neq D' \in D(X,d)$ the 
$L(D)$ and $L(D')$ may be not disjoint where in order to 
add dimensions like for products we have to be sure
that $L(D) $ (which we identify with $L(D) \times \{D\} $) and $L(D') $ (which we identify with $L(D) \times \{D'\} $) has to be *disjoint*. That was my concern in previous comments.

Comment: But I think now you precisely hit the essential point
that answers my concern. We want to count the dimension
generically, that's it's suffice to pass somehow
to open dense sets $V \subset D(X,d)$ and family of 
open dense subsets $U_D \subset L(D)$ for $D \in V$, with 
property $U_D \cap U_{D'} = \emptyset$ for $D \neq D' \in V$,
that was your argument, right?

Comment: A nitpick: for fixed divisor $D$ with respect which topology
$U_D$ is open dense in $L(D)$ in your considerations? 
You remaked that the elements of $L(D)$ with pole divisor $\neq D$ live in a
a Zariski-closed subset of strictly smaller dimension. I'm
confused here, do you mean that in the sense that you 
endow here each $L(D)$ with affine Zariski topology using the 
identification $L(D)= \mathbb{C}^{d-g+1}$ and by alg closeness
identify elements in $\mathbb{C}^{d-g+1}$ with  primes?

Comment: Okay, glad that cleared up your doubt. Yes, that was my argument. Right, $L(D)$ is a vector space, so we can identify it with affine space $\mathbb{A}^{d-g+1}$ and equip it with the Zariski topology. I think the set of elements with pole divisor $\neq D$ are a linear subspace: by choosing a basis $h_1, \ldots, h_{d-g+1}$ of $L(D)$ with distinct pole orders, the set of such elements should correspond to setting some of the coefficients $a_i=0$ in a linear combination $a_1 h_1 + \cdots + a_{d-g+1} h_{d-g+1}$.